# Need ignore several lines in command diff, when compare two PDF document

Tags: regex, ubuntu, pdf, compare, diff

I try compare two PDF document. And I know in what lines we have differences.

I want ignore this lines.

command: `diff -a -t -I'^/CreationDate' -I'^/ModDate' -I'^/ID' -I'^<</Filter' 2707_1.pdf 2707_3.pdf`

result:

```
69c69

...

84,89c84,89

...

338,341c338,347
```

I want ignore only this 338,341c338,347. How to ignore exactly this lines in document?

I know that here must be user regular expression, but I can't understand what I need to use. I try many options but still can't get result what I need.

On this lines present pictures, that doesn't need to compare. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.